# Aggregate data frame by date and apply different functions to corresponding columns?

Tags: r, sum, aggregate, average, max

I have the following data frame "DF" which is part of a much larger one:

```
             X1  X2            X3 X4 X5
4468 2010-03-24   3  1.000000e+00  1  2
7662 2010-03-24   9  3.000000e+00  2  1
1272 2010-03-25   8  2.000000e+00  1  1
1273 2010-03-26   9  0.000000e+00  1  1
1274 2010-03-27   8  0.000000e+00  1  1
4469 2010-03-28   4  0.000000e+00  1  2
7663 2010-03-28   4  3.000000e+00  3  1
8734 2010-03-28   7  4.000000e+00  2  3
1275 2010-03-29   8  0.000000e+00  1  1
```

As you can see the first column contains a date. What I want to do is as follows:
I want to transform this dataframe to a new one "DF2" where there is only 1 row per date with corresponding column values:

```
X2, the average 
X3, the sum
X4, the maximum
```

of all previous values per date. X5 is not relevant and can be removed. This would be the result:

```
             X1  X2            X3 X4
7662 2010-03-24   6  4.000000e+00  2  
1272 2010-03-25   8  2.000000e+00  1  
1273 2010-03-26   9  0.000000e+00  1  
1274 2010-03-27   8  0.000000e+00  1  
8734 2010-03-28   5  7.000000e+00  3  
1275 2010-03-29   8  0.000000e+00  1
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ddply` function from the plyr package to do arbitrary aggregations or other transforms by some grouping variable.

For your question the code would look something like:

```
library(plyr)
result <- ddply(DF, .(X1), function(df) {
  with(df, data.frame( X1=mean(X1), X2=sum(X2), X3=max(X3) ) )
} )
```

If this is a medium-large project then you may want to set the `progress` argument to show a progress bar.  For a really large problem it can be set to use parallel processing.

Comment: `summarise` is an alternative option to the anonymous function.

Comment: I think parallelization will only help if one of the functions is the speed bottle neck, which would probably not be the case for `mean`, `sum`, or `max`.

Answer (score 9):

```
DF <- read.table(text="             X1  X2            X3 X4 X5
4468 2010-03-24   3  1.000000e+00  1  2
7662 2010-03-24   9  3.000000e+00  2  1
1272 2010-03-25   8  2.000000e+00  1  1
1273 2010-03-26   9  0.000000e+00  1  1
1274 2010-03-27   8  0.000000e+00  1  1
4469 2010-03-28   4  0.000000e+00  1  2
7663 2010-03-28   4  3.000000e+00  3  1
8734 2010-03-28   7  4.000000e+00  2  3
1275 2010-03-29   8  0.000000e+00  1  1",header=TRUE)

library(data.table)

DT <- as.data.table(DF)

DT[,list(X2=mean(X2),X3=sum(X3),X4=max(X4)),by=X1]

#            X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1: 2010-03-24  6  4  2
# 2: 2010-03-25  8  2  1
# 3: 2010-03-26  9  0  1
# 4: 2010-03-27  8  0  1
# 5: 2010-03-28  5  7  3
# 6: 2010-03-29  8  0  1
```

Comment: not sure if the rownames are important piece of data or not.  If so, the DT statement can be `DT <- data.table(DF, rowName=rownames(DF))`

Comment: When the mean of several rows is taken, which rowname would you assign? I don't think rownames are important here.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific.  My comment was more of a general sort if the user wants to continue using the `DT` in lieu of the original `DF`, beyond the scope of just this specific task

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to do this but here is an [sqldf](http://sqldf.googlecode.com) solution:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select X1, avg(X2), sum(X3), max(X4) from DF group by X1")
```

The result is:

```
          X1 avg(X2) sum(X3) max(X4)
1 2010-03-24       6       4       2
2 2010-03-25       8       2       1
3 2010-03-26       9       0       1
4 2010-03-27       8       0       1
5 2010-03-28       5       7       3
6 2010-03-29       8       0       1
```

Answer (score 1):

And here is the `dplyr` way :

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
   group_by(X1) %>%
   summarise(X2 = mean(X2), 
             X3 = sum(X3), 
             X4 = max(X4))

#  X1            X2    X3    X4
#  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 2010-03-24    6.    4.    2.
#2 2010-03-25    8.    2.    1.
#3 2010-03-26    9.    0.    1.
#4 2010-03-27    8.    0.    1.
#5 2010-03-28    5.    7.    3.
#6 2010-03-29    8.    0.    1.
```